# Getting member size from zip using Archive::Zip::MemberRead

Tags: perl, zip

I am trying to read each member file size from a zip without actually extracting.  I iterate through all member names, then use `Archive::Zip::MemberRead` to get a file handle for each member, against which I was hoping to be able to use the `stat` method to get the size.  However, `stat` on a file handle from a zip file element returns an empty array so I can't get my file size.  Here is my code:

```
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new($zipFilePath);

my @mbrs = $zip->memberNames();

foreach my $mbrName(@mbrs)
{
    my $fh  = Archive::Zip::MemberRead->new($zip, $mbrName);

    my @fileStats = stat($fh);
    my $size = $fileStats[7];

    print "\n".$mbrName." -- ".$size;
}
```

However, the output I get does not display any file size:

```
dir/fileName1.txt --
dir/fileName2.txt --
```

The question is how to retrieve member file sizes without actually extracting them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use the `Archive::Zip` module itself? This seems to work for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Archive::Zip qw(:ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS);

my $filename = "somezipfile.zip";

# Read in the ZIP file    
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
unless ($zip->read($filename) == AZ_OK) {
    die "Read error\n";
}

# Loop through the members, printing their name,
# compressed size, and uncompressed size.
my @members = $zip->members();
foreach (@members)
{
    print " - " . $_->fileName() . ": " . $_->compressedSize() .
      " (" . $_->uncompressedSize() . ")\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way only if you have [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) installed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

## List files from zip file provided as first argument to the script, the format 
## is like:
#   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
#------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
#2012-10-19 16:56:38 .....          139          112  1.txt
#2012-10-19 16:56:56 .....          126          105  2.txt
#2012-10-19 16:57:24 .....           71           53  3.txt
#2012-10-03 14:39:54 .....          155           74  A.txt
#2012-09-29 17:53:44 .....          139           70  AA.txt
#2011-12-08 10:41:16 .....           30           30  AAAB.txt
#2011-12-08 10:41:16 .....           18           18  AAAC.txt
# ...
for ( map { chomp; $_ } qx/7z l $ARGV[0]/ ) { 

    # Omit headers and footers with this flip-flop.
    if ( my $l = ( m/^(?:-+\s+){2,}/ ... m/^(?:-+\s+){2,}/ ) ) { 

        ## Don't match flip-flop boundaries.
        next if $l == 1 || $l =~ m/E0$/;

        ## Extract file name and its size.
        my @f = split ' ';
        printf qq|%s -- %d bytes\n|, $f[5], $f[3];
    }   
}
```

I run it like:

```
perl script.pl files.zip
```

That yiedls in my test (with some output suppressed):

```
1.txt -- 139 bytes
2.txt -- 126 bytes
3.txt -- 71 bytes
A.txt -- 155 bytes
AA.txt -- 139 bytes
AAAB.txt -- 30 bytes
AAAC.txt -- 18 bytes
B.txt -- 40 bytes
BB.txt -- 131 bytes
C.txt -- 4 bytes
CC.txt -- 184 bytes
File1.txt -- 177 bytes
File2.txt -- 250 bytes
aaa.txt -- 30 bytes
...
```